# Polymorphism for variables in C#

Tags: c#, oop, polymorphism

Is there a way to implement polymorphism for variables in C#?

Basically I want to write something like this:

```
public class BaseClass
{
}

public class FinalClass : BaseClass
{
}

public class A
{
   public BaseClass BaseClassProperty {get; set;}
}

public class B : A
{
   public override FinalClass BaseClassProperty {get; set;}
}
```

I do know about Generics, but I thnk it's not always a good solution since you can end up with something like this -

```
 public class A<T,V,C>
 {
    public T TValue;
    public V VValue;
    public C CValue;
 }
```

I also know about keyword "new" but I find it too "cheesy".

EDIT:
I'll explain my situation to avoid XY problem.

```
public abstract class BaseGameManager
{
    public BaseAccount account;
}                         

public abstract class BaseAccount
{
}

public class GameManager : BaseGameManager
{
    public Account account;
}                         

public class Account : BaseAccount
{
}
```

Sometimes, I'll be referencing my object as a GameManager and sometimes as a BaseGameManager. When I'll be referncing it as a GameManager I don't want to cast account property to a Account class every time. That's my problem. I was talking about generics being too much since account will not be the only property to inherit the way I described.

Comment: this smells of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Also, `new` is cheesy?  How do you write any programs at all without instantiating anything?

Comment: You won't be able to do this, because `(new B()).BaseClassProperty = new BaseClass()` has to be able to compile. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @BradleyUffner He doesn't mean `new` as allocating a new object, he means `new` as shadowing a variable of a parent.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I suspect the OP means [`new` when used to hide an underlying member](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx)

Comment: @BradleyUffner I meant "new" as visibility modifier.

Comment: What your trying to do doesn't make sense. Any class consuming B would need to know `BaseClassProperty`  was a `FinalClass`. similarly any problem consuming A would have no idea what instance `BaseClassProperty` was. So the declaration in A is pointless. What exactly is the underlying problem your trying to solve?

Comment: Using `new` would solve his problem.  Anything from B up would use `FinalClass` anything from A down would use `BaseClass` (including instances of `FinalClass`)

Comment: If you have to use `new` on multiple variables, I'd say there's a design problem with your code.

Answer (score 1):

> I do know about Generics, but I thnk it's not always a good solution since you can end up with something like this

Well, that is a perfect solution. Generics are the way to go if you want to type your classes dynamically.

You class `A` would just need one generic type parameter, which doesn't seem a lot to me. I have some very core base classes and they have quite some generic type parameters, and still it is a lot easier to work with than if I didn't have that.

Proposed code:

```
public class A<BC> where BC : BaseClass
{
   public BC BaseClassProperty {get; set;}
}

public class B : A<FinalClass>
{ }
```

Comment: Well, it is a ORM mapper, so you can understand you have collections, rows, fields, relations, that are the 4 most common ones...

Comment: It is complex of course, that is why all code on top of it is automatically generated. That saves us typing the 'same' classes 300 times :).

Comment: Auto generated classes, that always adds to the fun :)

Comment: Well, I think one or two generic parameters is fine, but I think in my case I can end up with more than 5.

Comment: I personally would check if the design really calls for that amount of generic type parameters. See if you can redesign some parts so that they can be joined together or omitted. If you really need those, I don't see problems in having 5 of them.

Answer (score 0):

What you want violates the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle):

```
var x = new B();

A a = x;  // works, because B is a subtype of A

// Compiles, since BaseClassProperty is of type BaseClass,
// but fails, since B only accepts a FinalClass.
a.BaseClassProperty = new BaseClass();
```

So, no, "polymorphism for variables" *in the way demonstrated by your example* cannot be legal in any language where the LSP holds. Of course, other types of polymorphism (for example, `B` being a subclass of `A<FinalClass>`) are possible.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: I thought that the implicit "no" is obvious enough, but I've added a sentence for this purpose.

Comment: Funny, I literally *just* finished reading about LSP minutes ago and didn't think of it when making my answer. Time to pay more attention.

Comment: This actually would work but if a was cast to B then you would get an exception.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do something like your A/B example. Here is an example of why it won't work:

```
A actuallyA = new A();
A actuallyB = new B(); // Totally legal

actuallyA.BaseClassProperty = new BaseClass();
actuallyA.BaseClassProeprty = new FinalClass();

actuallyB.BaseClassProperty = new FinalClass(); // What B allows
// Because actuallyB is referenced locally as an A, that definition would allow it,
// however this would fail because B only allows the one base type.
actuallyB.BaseClassProperty = new BaseClass();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make this work very easily but yet, you will need to use the "cheesy" `new`

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = new B();

        a.Prop = new MyBase();

        Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", a.Prop); // 'classtest.MyBase'
        Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", ((B)a).Prop); // ''

        a.Prop = new Final();
        Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", a.Prop); // 'classtest.Final'
        Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", ((B)a).Prop); // 'classtest.Final'
    }
}

public class MyBase
{
}
public class Final : MyBase
{
}

public class A
{
    public MyBase Prop { get; set; }
}
public class B : A
{
    public new Final Prop
    {
        get { return base.Prop as Final; }
        set { base.Prop = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the getter exposed in A and b you could do something like this.

```
public class BaseClass
{
}

public class FinalClass : BaseClass
{
}

public class A
{
    private BaseClass baseProp;
    public virtual BaseClass BaseClassProperty {get { return baseProp; } }
}

public class B : A
{
    private FinalClass finalProp;
    public override BaseClass BaseClassProperty {get { return finalProp; } }
}
```